# CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent not working on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I created a Hololens app using MRTK and Vuforia, this app starts with a menu where the user can chose between 4 scenarios. Following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/supported-devices/using-ar-foundation?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) from Microsoft, I'm now trying to deploy this app on an Android device. For you information the app works perfectly fine on the Hololens and in the Unity Editor.

**The problem**
I can build the `.apk`, deploy it and launch the app on the Android device and click on buttons (I hear the sound) but it doesn't change the scene.

**What I've tried**
My buttons have a script attached which requires the name of the scene to load.
[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// Request that the MRTK SceneSystem load a scene of a given name.
    public void LoadScene(string sceneName) => CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

I use the same script with an hard coded `sceneName` to load the first scene (the menu) which is loaded and displayed on the Android device.

In the build settings I selected all the scenes and the `minimum API level` is set to `level 30`

[image]

What could cause this behaviour where the scenes aren't loaded except for the first one ?

[EDIT] I also tried to use `SceneManager.LoadScene(id)` but it's also not working on the Android device

This picture show the ARFoundation and ARCore version used
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Android isn't detecting events triggered by `OnClick` so you must use `OnPress` while the Hololens supports both

[image]